# Java Spring boot with maven. How to configure profiles?

Tags: java, spring, maven, profile

I have problem with setting profiles in my spring boot app. I use java with react and currently am learning how to deploy app to aws. For development I was using docker image of postgres db and this config file (application.yml):

```
app:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/karatesandemo
    username: username
    password: password
    pool-size: 30
```

For my aws db I had to make diffrent configuration, so i made another file (application-prod.yml):

```
server:
  port: 5000
app:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:URL:5432/karatesandemo
    username: username
    password: password
    pool-size: 30
```

And this is my pom.xml profile:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                            <workingDirectory>${frontend.src.directory}</workingDirectory>
                            <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm-install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-ui</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-react-build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${frontend.src.directory}/build</directory>
                                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Problem is when i want to install it with mvn clean install -Pprod. it keeps taking application.yml configuration (No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default").

I've been trying to fiddle with adding :

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @spring.profiles.active@
```

To application.yml files and it stayed same. What works for me is deleting it from application-prod.yml and leaving it in application.yml. Only this way it works. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Maven profiles and spring profiles are different things. DOn't mix them. Ditch the maven prod profile. Just build your jar and when running in production include `--spring.profiles.active=prod` when running the application. Don't rebuild your application just because you want to move to a different environment. Or instead of a profile just pass the properties `--spring.datasource.url=<url>` etc. or specify them as environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you elaborate it though? What do you mean by ditching maven prod profile? In this profile I use maven frontend plugin to install locally node and react app.

Comment: That isn't the only thing you do. Just make it part of your regular build. You are also building it with the assumption that it automatically enables spring profiles, which it doesn't.